# Testing Class with @Injectable Scope / @Inject(REQUEST) NestJS

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-testing

I have set up a MongooseConfigService to allow us to dynamically switch out the connection string for certain requests and am trying to get the tests set up correctly.

```
@Injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class MongooseConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request) {
  }
```

I am however having trouble providing `request` to the test context.

```
  let service: Promise<MongooseConfigService>;
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const req = new JestRequest();
    
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MongooseConfigService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken(REQUEST),
          inject: [REQUEST],
          useFactory: () => ({
            request: req,
          }),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    
    service = module.resolve<MongooseConfigService>(MongooseConfigService);
  });
```

This is as far as I have gotten, have tried it without the `inject` and with/without `useValue`, however `this.request` remains undefined when trying to run the tests.

TIA

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [docs on testing request scoped services](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#testing-request-scoped-instances)?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, yeah, but with 5 lines of code and no apparent context around how to actually use, it does not get one very far.

Comment: What is JestRequest()? Did you created it yourself or is part of the Jest dependency?

Comment: @CedricAchi I can only assume it's part of their dependencies or another package, have not touched this project or JS for that matter in over a year.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe try to instantiate the testing module with only import: [appModule] and then try to get the service. also, try to use overrideprovider and usevalue like this:

```
let service: Promise<MongooseConfigService>;
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const req = new JestRequest();
    
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [appModule]
    }).overrideProvider(REQUEST)
      .useValue(req)
      .compile();
    
    service = module.resolve<MongooseConfigService>(MongooseConfigService);
  });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, although you pass req into useValue, not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and found a slightly easier method.

```js
let service: MongooseConfigService;

beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
            MongooseConfigService, // or whatever your service is
            {
                provide: REQUEST,
                useValue: { user: { idpId: 'idpId' } },
            },
        ],
    }).compile();
    service = await module.resolve(MongooseConfigService);
});
```

In my case I only needed to retrieve certain user details from the request, so this was easy. You could easily substitute the useValue here with the JestRequest noted in the other answer. My experience is that you are often already using multiple providers in this way, which makes this quite easy to add as just another provider.